# Documenting nested macros in C with Doxygen

Tags: c, macros, doxygen

Suppose I have a file defining hundreds of macros to be accessed as event numbers and names.

```
event.h

// Define events as an enum
#define DEFINE_EVENT(name, value)   EVENT_##name = value,
enum {
  include "events_list.txt"
} #undef DEFINE_EVENT

// Define an array of the event names
#define DEFINE_EVENT(name, value)   [value] = #name,
const char* const EVENT_NAMES[] = {
  #include "events_list.txt"
};
#undef DEFINE_EVENT
```

```
events_list.txt

//! Calling this event will do something awesome
DEFINE_EVENT(A, 0)
//! Calling this event will do something absurd
DEFINE_EVENT(B, 1)
//! Calling this event will do something crazy
DEFINE_EVENT(C, 2)
...
```

The above will create an enum of events which we can then access such that `EVENT_A = 1`, `EVENT_B = 2`, etc.

The problem is that I would also like to document these events in doxygen such that they display with their event name (EVENT_#), value and description. But because I am making macro calls in `events_list.txt` and not defining macros, running doxygen isn't populating as I would expect. My initial thought was to write a script to generate a more "doxygen friendly file" that essentially makes:

```
events_list_for_doxygen.txt

//! Calling this event will do something awesome
#define EVENT_A   0
//! Calling this event will do something absurd
#define EVENT_B   1
//! Calling this event will do something crazy
#define EVENT_C   2
...
```

but then I would have to maintain this generated file. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Given a choice between X-macros and a code generator, I'd go with the code generator. But before choosing either of those two options, I'd take a long hard look at the underlying problem, and see if there is a solution that doesn't involve maintaining a list of hundreds of macros.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? For this type of problems I think you should have a look at the filter possibilities of doxygen (see e.g. `INPUT_FILTER`).